Rcapture package Error in 1:dim(X[, 1:t])[1] : argument of length 0
I'm using Rcapture package to estimate the population size in diferent sampling sites.
However, in some site I only caught 1 individual in a 4-night live trapping sessions.
So, for this sites I have the columns "A", "B", "C", "D" with the values "0","0","0","1", respectively (where 0 means no capture and 1 means capture).
When I run
descC_EP1<-descriptive(ch_control_EP1)

or
closedp.bc("data") 

result in this error:

Error in 1:dim(X[, 1:t])[1] : argument of length 0

How can I resolve this problem?

descC_EP1<-descriptive("data") or closedp.bc("data")
